# Get rid of Outlook search popup?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, popups

Every time I open Outlook, I get the popup in the screenshot below.  I've clicked a mixture of `Not now` and `Next` - both of which close the popup until next time I open outlook.  (Should clicking `Next` do something different?)

How can I stop this happening?  Not a big problem I know but it's annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I know, that welcome popup will only appear once after you update it. You could try the registry method UbaIsTheName mentioned above and see if there is any difference. If the issue continues, please try [repairing your Office installation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's a demonstration on what are the new features of Outlook.

Clicking "**Next**" will probably trigger another pop-up.
So keep clicking "**Next**" until there is the last pop-up that will ask you to finish.

After finishing the pop-up sequence, it will probably not happen again.

This happens sometimes in Softwares that are updated and it's a way to keep the user informed on what's new!

If this won't work, let me know.

Comment: No it doesn't work - I specifically mentioned in my question that when I clicked `Next` I get the same behaviour as clicking `Not now`.  The box disappears and reappears next time I start outlook.  Thanks for taking the time to reply though.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read this properly, you are right.
I found a user with a similar problem and it eventually it solved itself.
You can find the link here.
[link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/get-rid-of-welcome-to-new-search-in-outlook/6f8594ba-b818-4653-9429-c6356a6ba2fe)

You can try this though:


Go to **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\WhatsNew** and create a new DWORD value named "SuppressForAutomation" and set the value to 1.
Save it, restart the PC and see if that pop up still occurs. Let me know if this worked!